# Private Blockchain mining contract

Tags: mining, private-blockchain

I am new in the blockchain world and I am trying to understand the following. any help will be highly appreciable. This is my understanding after several videos and courses.

- I have a private Azure blockchain.
- I have created a contact and deployed it.
- once it is mined by Ethereum I will get an address.
- Later I can use the address and add data to it.

My question is

Does the time it take to mine has any relation to the complexity of my contract?

Do I really need to mine? because I am not using the blockchain for coins for a different use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mining is a heart of Proof Of Work consensus algorithm. It is essentially a puzzle which miners have to solve in order to generate proof of work and validate a transaction. It is computationally intensive.

Private blockchain has different consensus algorithms for validating transactions. 
For example,`Quorum` is popularly used for developing enterprise blockchain applications. It uses voting based consensus algorithms such as `Raft, Quorumchain, and Istanbul`. `geth` has an option to use `Proof Of Authority` consensus algorithm for private blockchain network.

In all the above-mentioned consensus algorithms process of validating blocks remains the same i.e. solve the cryptographic puzzle(mining).

In the case of `Raft` consensus only elected `leader` will do mining and broadcast it to all the participants in the blockchain network.

In case of Proof Of Authority consensus algorithm of `geth` only authorized nodes will do mining.

Proces of validating block is the same(mining) depending on consensus algorithm that you select for private blockchain only selected nodes will do the process of mining. In the case of the public blockchain network, all the participating nodes will compete for rewards received after mining the block successfully.